# Terminal в среде Pycharm не дает писать заглавные буквы англ алфавита

Tags: python, консоль, pycharm, pyinstaller

Установил через пейчарм модуль pyinstaller. Хотел упаковать код в exe файл через команду  pyinstaller main.py -F, написанную в терминале. Но терминал не дает написать заглавные английские буквы, даже вставить готовую строку не дает

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё один способ упаковать в exe файл. Через терминал установить auto-py-to-exe `pip install auto-py-to-exe`. Затем в терминале вызываем команду `auto-py-to-exe`. В открывшемся приложении пишем путь к файлу main.py и запускаем. Готовый exe файл можно сразу запустить.